# GUI for Knopflerfish Config Admin

Tags: user-interface, configuration, admin, config, knopflerfish

Does anybody know about a GUI for Config Admin of Knopflerfish? What I want to achieve is dynamic configuration management without editting configuration files manually. Is that possible at all? Here [OSGI blog](http://blog.osgi.org/2010/06/how-to-use-config-admin.html) I read that

> To set Config Admin data, take a look at the Felix Webconsole, Felix FileInstall, or the Knopflerfish environment. They all support a range of (G)UIs to create configuration records.

But I could not find any GUI for Knopflerfish :(

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you're still interested in this topic, anyway I hope I can help you.
What I tried so far are the possibility to change the ConfigAdmin data via:

1. Felix FileInstall (download the bundle from http://felix.apache.org/downloads.cgi) and add it to your init.xargs list of bundles to install and start. Then every modification you make in the pair "properties = value" of the file myBundle.cfg is notified to bundles registered as ManagedService with pid = myBundle. EXPLANATION ADDED FOR COMPLETENESS BUT THIS IS NOT A GUI TOOL!
2. Knopflerfish Console: from here you can enter the "configuration" submenu with "enter configuration", then "list" to see the available configurations with relative pids and "edit *pids_name*" if you want to change a configuration dynamically. To change a property value use "set *property_name* *value*"
3. Felix WebConsole: following [this](http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-web-console.html) guide you can install the webConsole which allows you to access the properties of your ManagedService via web console at the port 8080 on the localhost (with default configuration). [Here](http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-web-console.data/console-config.png) how you can see the interface of ConfigAdmin via Felix WebConsole.

I hope it helped to you or omeone else reading in th future.

Andrea